# Add a pointer to a beginning of array (of pointers) in C

Tags: c, c-strings

I have an array of char pointers

```
char ** strings
```

with the length of

```
limit
```

I'm trying to add a char pointer to the beginning of the array, while maintaining all the arrays objects except the last one
For example, if my array had 3 pointers:

```
 {*str1, *str2, *str3}
```

and I want to add `*str4` to the beginning, it'll look like this:

```
 {*str4, *str1, *str2}
```

while keeping the same size

Hope I'm being clear enough

Thank you

**EDIT**

I'm trying to avoid looping the whole thing to move the pointers. I'm looking for a O(1) solution for this

Comment: Why don't make a linked list with pointers to head and tail?

Comment: I think that you need a queue http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done with linked-list concept.[Insertion at First)

Steps:

1)Element declaration.

```
 struct element{
char *dataPtr;
struct element *next;
};
```

2)Head element declaration in main.

```
struct element *head;
```

3)pass head to your insertion functions as

```
struct element *new =(struct element *)malloc(sizeof(element));
insert(&head,new)
```

4) In insert function,

```
if (*head == NULL)
{
*head = new;
new ->Next = *head;
}
else
{
new->Next = *head;
*head = new;
}
```

In those step, you don't need to traverse entire linked list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add one pointer at the beginning than you have to increment the others pointers from theirs place with 1 element

The behaviour that you are looking for: adding a pointer at the head and remove the one in the tail (no actions else): could be done only with linked list

Answer (score 0):

If you use `char **` to store your pointers to strings then there isn't an O(1) solution, just the obvious O(n) one.  Although, you could probably do a memcpy for the (n-1) pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this concept code. It should respect the O(1) requirement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char **strings;
    char **strings2;

    // init pointers with mnemonic memory addresses just for demo purposes
    char *p1 = (char *) 0x01;
    char *p2 = (char *) 0x02;
    char *p3 = (char *) 0x03;
    char *p4 = (char *) 0x04;

    // define the size of pointe array
    int limit = 3;

    // malloc main
    strings = malloc(sizeof(char *) * limit);

    // fill up the pointer array
    strings[0] = p1;
    strings[1] = p2;
    strings[2] = p3;

    // debug - print out the initial state of pointers
    printf("p1 %p p2 %p p3 %p p4 %p\n", p1, p2, p3, p4);
    printf("original pointer array: %p %p %p\n", strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);

    // create another array of pointers and fill it up with shifted data
    // and the new entry on the head
    strings2 = malloc(sizeof(char *) * limit);
    memcpy(strings2 + 1, strings, (limit - 1)  * sizeof(char *));
    strings2[0] = p4;

    // free the original one and make it point to the modified array
    free(strings);
    strings = strings2;

    printf("new pointer array: %p %p %p\n", strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);

    free(strings);
}
```

Result:

```
[root@mysrvr test]# ./a.out
p1 0x1 p2 0x2 p3 0x3 p4 0x4
original pointer array: 0x1 0x2 0x3
new pointer array: 0x4 0x1 0x2
```